# How to change dynamic variable in Revel Template

Tags: html, go, type-conversion, go-templates, revel

In my revel project, i have a select option that need to get selected after clicking submit button.

If i do it like this it works because `.OptionType` is a string so i need to compare it with string

```
<select class="chosen form-control" id="selectType">
    <option disabled value='' style="display:none"> --------- </option>
    <option  {{ if eq .OptionType "1" }}selected{{end}} value="1">Option A</option>
    <option {{ if eq .OptionType "2" }}selected{{end}} value="2">Option B</option>
    <option  {{ if eq .OptionType "3" }}selected{{end}} value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

But if i try to compare variable like `.ID` it throws an error

```
<select class="chosen form-control" id="selectValue">
    <option {{ if eq .SelectedValue "all" }} selected {{end}} value='all'>
        All Value
    </option>
    {{range .Circles}}
        <option {{ if eq .SelectedValue .ID }} selected {{end}} value='{{.ID}}'>
            {{.Name}}
        </option>
    {{end}}
</select>
```

Is there any way that i could convert `.ID` in the same line with if statement ?

Error Message:

**executing "BackendReport/Finance.html" at <.SelectedValue>: can't evaluate field SelectedValue in type models.Value**

Comment: What is the error

Comment: here's the error message executing "BackendReport/Finance.html" at <.SelectedValue>: can't evaluate field SelectedValue in type models.Value

Comment: The problem is not .ID. It is SelectedValue. It is in a `range` context, so it is looking up fields in an element of .Circles. Try $.SelectedValue

Comment: there's error
executing "BackendReport/Finance.html" at <eq $.SelectedValue .ID>: error calling eq: incompatible types for comparison

Answer (score 1):

`template.go`

```
revel.TemplateFuncs["toString"] = func(val interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(val)
}
```

`.html`

```
{{$current_value := .SelectedValue -}}
    {{range .Circles}}
        <option  {{ if eq $current_value (toString .ID)  }}selected{{end}} value='{{.ID}}'>
            {{.Name}}
        </option>
    {{end}}
```

This works in me. Hope its help you.

Comment: `print` is a builtin template function doing the same as your `toString`, so you don't need to register any function, just use `{{ if eq $current_value (print .ID) }}`